# Create a gdoc from an image (OCR)

Tags: google-drive-api

How do I reproduce programmatically the manual task of right-click on an image -> Open With -> Google Docs with Drive SDK?
This task creates a new Google Doc with the same name with the image's OCR content.

I am working with the .Net client but answers about any other client would do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i never tried, but this page seems helpful even if related to google cloud service.
https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/ocr

Comment: Since my question was posted Google released their Vision API, which does exactly that. Thanks!